# How do I inject a return type in a method that returns multiple types?

Tags: c#, generics

```
 public T SomeMethod<T>(){

   if(somecondition==something) return 999;
   if(somecondition==somethingelse) return "String";

 }
```

The problem is that both those return statements receive design time errors which indicate they are not of type T.

Caller code would look like this.

```
int ID = SomeMethod<int>();
string StringVaule = SomeMethod<string>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question was:

```
return (T)(object) 999;
```

or

```
return (T)(object) "String";
```

I call this a "double cast"...